# Arduino GPS direction/Heading program not giving accurate readings

Tags: arduino

I am trying to write an Arduino Program that is supposed to write GPS direction/Heading on an LCD display however I am having issues getting the Heading to read accurate readings and to update more often than once every 15 minutes if even that. Is there a specific thing I need to change in the code to get it to read accurate readings and to update more often or is it just the way it is? I am using a Bingfu GPS antenna and a Arduino Mega 2560 board to make this happen.

My code is here below it compiles and works well but it only updates ever so often and doesn't update when I move the GPS antenna like its supposed too.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // Include the LCD library
#include <TinyGPS++.h>    // Include TinyGPS++ library

// Pins for the GPS module

const int GPSRX = 10;
const int GPSTX = 11;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); // Set the LCD address and dimensions

// Define software serial port for GPS (adjust if using hardware serial)
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(GPSRX, GPSTX);

// Create TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// Function to convert degrees to cardinal direction
const char* getCardinalDirection(double degrees) {
  if (degrees > 337.5 || degrees <= 22.5) {
    return "N";
  } else if (degrees > 22.5 && degrees <= 67.5) {
    return "NE";
  } else if (degrees > 67.5 && degrees <= 112.5) {
    return "E";
  } else if (degrees > 112.5 && degrees <= 157.5) {
    return "SE";
  } else if (degrees > 157.5 && degrees <= 202.5) {
    return "S";
  } else if (degrees > 202.5 && degrees <= 247.5) {
    return "SW";
  } else if (degrees > 247.5 && degrees <= 292.5) {
    return "W";
  } else {
    return "NW";
  }
}

// Function to calculate direction to a destination
double getDirectionToDestination(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
  double dLon = lon2 - lon1;
  double y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
  double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
  double brng = atan2(y, x);
  brng = degrees(brng);
  brng = fmod((brng + 360), 360);
  return brng;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Open serial communication for debugging
  gpsSerial.begin(9600); // Start software serial for GPS

  // Set up LCD backlight and contrast
  lcd.init(); // Initialize the LCD
  lcd.backlight(); // Turn on the backlight

  // Display welcome message
  lcd.print("GPS Tracker");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Initializing...");
}

void loop()
{
  // Read data from GPS module
  while (gpsSerial.available())
  {
    gps.encode(gpsSerial.read());
  }

  // Check for GPS fix
  if (gps.location.isValid())
  {
    // Get current heading in degrees
    double heading = gps.course.deg();

    // Convert heading to cardinal direction
    const char* direction = getCardinalDirection(heading);

    // Get latitude and longitude of destination (example values)
    double destLat = 37.7749;
    double destLon = -122.4194;

    // Calculate direction to destination
    double directionToDest = getDirectionToDestination(gps.location.lat(), gps.location.lng(), destLat, destLon);

    // Display heading and direction to destination on LCD
    lcd.clear(); // Clear LCD
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Direction: ");
    lcd.print(directionToDest, 1);
    lcd.print("");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Heading: ");
    lcd.print(heading, 1); // Display heading with one decimal place
    lcd.print("");
    lcd.print(direction);
  }
  else
  {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("No GPS fix");
  }

  delay(1000); // Update display every second
}
```

Comment: If you have a Mega, then why are you using SoftwareSerial?  That's for when you are out of Serial ports and need to fake one.  The Mega has 4 real serial ports.  Use one of them.

Comment: It's what was required to use SoftwareSerial. That's why I am using it. Will it not work if it's using that??

Comment: No, it is NOT required to use SoftwareSerial.  It is required to use a serial interface.  The example you looked at was probably written for an UNO which only has one serial port.  Since that port would be connected to the PC for output, they used SoftwareSerial to fake another one.  You have a Mega.  It has 4 real serial ports.  Only one of them is going to the PC.  There are three (Serial1, Serial2, and Serial3) that are available for you to use.  You simply connect to (for Serial1) the Rx1 and Tx1 pins and use `Serial1.begin` and `Serial1.print` to talk to your GPS instead of gpsSerial

Comment: To test heading you will need to move the gps antenna a significant distance between readings. For initial tests I would make that several metres. If you are only moving it a small distance, that would explain inaccurate readings.